# css sticky position float bug

Tags: css, position, sticky

I use CSS position's sticky value when top div height isn't an int value but a float value then set bottom div's top same as top's height, it will have space between them! but use absolute and fixed don't have this issue.

a div and b div have space

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

.container > div {
  height: 65.9px;
}

.a {
  position: sticky;
  /* position: static */
  /* position: sticky */
  width: 340px;
  top: 0px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 20;
}

.b {
  position: sticky;
  top: 66px;
  /* top: 65.9 */
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: pink;
  over-flow: hidden;
}

.c {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  left: 120px;
  top: 66px;
  background: red;
}

.d {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  top: 66px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- position sticky float number bug -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a: height=65.9px sticky position</div>
  <div class="b">b: top=66px sticky position</div>
  <div class="c">c: top=66px fixed position</div>
  <div class="d">d: top=66px absolute</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to see it?

Comment: unclear to me :), where is the floatting buggy element ? where is it suppose to go wrong ?

Comment: a div and b div have space

Comment: Have space where?

Comment: use chrome browser to see

Comment: If you are talking about the vertical space between `a` div and `b` div, I cannot see that, and I'm using chrome browser only.